# Entity framework: T4 POCO, how to disable Fixup?

Tags: entity-framework, templates, entity-framework-4, t4

I would like to know if there is a way to disable the use of the FixupPropertyName with the T4 generator? Or if I've to delete some text in the generator?

Because I don't need it, I prefer to ensure myself the bidirectionnality than get unwanted handling(like in removing circular references).

Thank you

Comment: You must simply modify T4 template and remove the fixup. It is just a .NET code with some markup characters so you should be able to do that yourselves.

Comment: Sure, but I don't want to create the wheel again if there is an option which disable this fixup association OR if the T4 template already exists

Comment: No there isn't any option and I'm not aware of these templates but you can check DbContext template where Fixups are not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the .tt fle, you'll notice `region.Begin("Association Fixup");` (line 303) which ends on line 632. You might want to delete that area and see what you'll get.

Comment: It's not that easy, they are all references to this methods, the use of fixup collection, event to enable or not, ...